# In Laravel, how can I change the date and time format to display in full Portuguese?

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel, how can I change the date and time format to display in full Portuguese? Specifically, I want to display dates and times in the format "DIA da SEMANA, DIA de MÊS de ANO às HORAS:HORAS:SEGUNDOS". What is the correct way to set the default language and date format in Laravel, and are there any specific configuration files or code changes that I need to make?

I want to change the date and time format in Laravel in full to Portuguese. Already tried to change in various ways and failed.
I changed the formats using Carbon dddd, MMMM D, YYYY h: mm A instructions and couldn't

[image: I want it to be like this]

UserController.php

```
$dL = [];
$dV = [];
foreach(array_reverse($stack) as $d) {
    $dL[]. = Date::parse($d)->format('dS M');

}

foreach(array_reverse($stack) as $d) {
    $date = Carbon::parse($d)->format('Y-m-d');
    $start = $date.
    ' '.
    '00:00:00';
    $end = $date.
    ' '.
    '23:59:59';
    $dC = Signal::whereBetween('created_at', [$start, $end])->get();
    $dV[]. = count($dC);
}

$data['dV'] = $dV;
$data['dL'] = $dL;

return view('user.dashboard', $data);
}
```

signal-all.blade.php

```
@php
    $p = 0;
@endphp

@foreach($signal as $k => $p)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $k + $signal->firstItem() }}</td>
    <td>{{\Jenssegers\Date\Date::parse($p->created_at)->format('dS M, Y - h:i:s A')}}</td>
    <td>{{ $p->signal->title }}</td>
    <td>{{ $p->signal->asset->name }} - {{ $p->signal->symbol->name }} - {{ $p->signal->type->name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $p->signal->frame->name }} - {{ $p->signal->status->name }}</td>
```

App.php

```
'timezone' => 'America/Sao_Paulo',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Locale Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The application locale determines the default locale that will be used
    | by the translation service provider. You are free to set this value
    | to any of the locales which will be supported by the application.
    |
    */

    'locale' => 'pt',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Fallback Locale
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The fallback locale determines the locale to use when the current one
    | is not available. You may change the value to correspond to any of
    | the language folders that are provided through your application.
    |
    */

    'fallback_locale' => 'pt',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Multi-Language Supported Date Time Laravel Package for this type of Output. You may check. https://github.com/jenssegers/date

Easy to Use

```
use Jenssegers\Date\Date;
```

Date::setLocale('pt'); //For Portuguese

echo Date::now()->format('l j F Y H:i:s'); // sábado 9 novembro 2019 13:45:03

echo Date::parse('-1 day')->diffForHumans(); // 1 dia atrás

Comment: I was able to make the change to <td>{{\Jenssegers\Date\Date::parse($p->created_at)->format('l, j F Y às H:i:s')}}</td> But the result is this: sexta-feira, 8 novembro 2019 à43 19:11:43. 
I want the result to be this: sexta-feira, 8 novembro 2019 às 19:11:43

Comment: It was resolved by adding the format: <td>{{\Jenssegers\Date\Date::parse($p->created_at)->format('l, j F Y à\s H:i:s')}}</td> 
Thank you for your help